# embedding v8: accessing simple class

Tags: javascript, c++, v8, embedding

I've been following the [V8 embedder's guide](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#accesssors) example "Accessing Dynamic Variables", and have managed to adjust the given code so that it compiles correctly with the latest version. However, the example shows only how to define accessors for a Class. If I'd like to use javascript to modify an existing `Point` instance, how do I pass that through?

For example, I imagine this scenario:

C++:

```
Point* p=...
p->x=10;
....
//This is where I'm completely stuck
.... 
Handle<Script> handleScript=Local<Script>::New(isolate, ...);
handleScript->Run();

//now p->x should be 5
```

javascript:

```
p.x=5;
```

EDIT: it seems the easiest way would be something like: (continuing from the example)

```
context->Global()->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "p"), obj);
```

if there's a better way, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be: (continuing from the example)

```
context->Global()->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "p"), obj);
```